# jqGrid 4.x using Inline Editing, trying to implement autocomplete in single field

Tags: jqgrid, autocomplete, inline-editing

There are multitudes of answers regarding this question or situations similar to this question but, unfortunately, they all seem quite old and jqGrid has recently gone through a overhaul to v 4.x. Also, there are so many different ways to implement editing and adding, that it seems no two situations are identical. So, I have to repost this question with my specific code and ask for a specific answer.

Basically, I have three almost identical grids that I want to be able to edit INLINE and use an `autocomplete` for a single field which will populate two other fields based on the `select` method.

** Original Code**

```
var mmGrid = $('#orderMMGrid'),
    editingRowId,
    myEditParam = {
        keys: false,
        oneditfunc: function(id) {
            editingRowId = id;
            // have tried autocomplete here as well //
        },
        afterrestorefunc: function(id) {
            editingRowId = undefined;
        },
        extraparam: {
            ml_id: ml_id
        }
    },
    myAddParam = {
        rowID: 'new',
        position:'last',
        extraparam: {
            ml_id: ml_id
        }
    };
mmGrid.jqGrid({
    url: '/json/json.getMinorMaterialsOrder.php?ml_id=' + ml_id,
    datatype:'json',
    colNames: ['ID','Type','Supp','Vendor','PO#','MasTec Part#','Description','Ship Date','Qty Ord','Rcvd Date','Qty Rec','Material Manager Notes','Receiving Clerk Notes'],
    colModel: [
        {   name:'id',
            index:'id',
            hidden:true,
            key:false,
            search:false,
            viewable:false
        },
        {   name:'type',
            index:'type',
            width:40,
            sortable:false,
            editable:false,
            align:'center',
            editoptions:{defaultValue:'M'}
        },
        {   name:'supp',
            index:'supp',
            width:40,
            sortable:false,
            editable:false,
            align:'center',
            editoptions:{defaultValue:suppno}
        },
        {   name:'vendor_id',
            index:'o.vendor_id',
            width:75,
            sortable:true,
            sorttype:'text',
            align:'left',
            editable:true,
            classes:'ui-ellipsis',
            edittype:'select',
            editoptions:{dataUrl:'/jqg/jqg.selVendors.php'},
            editrules:{required:true}
        },
        {   name:'order_number',
            index:'order_number',
            width:55,
            sortable:false,
            editable:true,
            classes:'ui-ellipsis',
            align:'center'
        },
        {   name:'mastec_partno',
            index:'mastec_partno',
            width:120,
            sortable:false,
            editable:true,
            classes:'ui-ellipsis',
            edittype:'text',
            editoptions:{size:22},
            editrules:{required:true},
            searchoptions: {
                dataInit: function(e) {
                    $(e).autocomplete({
                        source: allMinorMaterials,
                        minLength: 2,
                        select: function(e,ui) {
                                  e.val(ui.item.id);
                                  $('input[name="description"]').text(ui.item.description);
                                  $('input[name="vendor_id"]').val(ui.item.vendor_id);
                                  return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        {   name:'description',
            index:'description',
            width:180,
            sortable:false,
            align:'left',
            editable:true,
            classes:'ui-ellipsis',
            edittype:'text',
            editoptions:{size:33},
            editrules:{required:true}
        },
        {   name:'ship_date',
            index:'o.ship_date',
            width:85,
            sortable:true,
            sorttype:'date',
            editable:true,
            align:'center',
            editrules:{required:true},
            editoptions:{   size:15,
                            dataInit: function(l) {
                                $(l).datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});
                            }
                        }
        },
        {   name:'qty_ordered',
            index:'qty_ordered',
            width:55,
            sortable:false,
            editable:true,
            align:'center',
            classes:'qtyOrd',
            editrules:{required:true},
            editoptions:{size:6}
        },
        {   name:'rcvd_date',
            index:'o.rcvd_date',
            width:85,
            sortable:true,
            sorttype:'date',
            editable:true,
            align:'center',
            editoptions:{   size:15,
                            dataInit:function(l) {
                                $(l).datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});
                            }
                        }
        },
        {   name:'qty_received',
            index:'qty_received',
            width:55,
            sortable:false,
            editable:true,
            align:'center',
            classes:'qtyRec',
            editoptions:{size:6}
        },
        {   name:'mm_notes',
            index:'mm_notes',
            width:250,
            sortable:false,
            editable:true,
            edittype:'textarea',
            classes:'ui-ellipsis',
            editoptions:{rows:'3',cols:'45'}
        },
        {   name:'rc_notes',
            index:'rc_notes',
            width:250,
            sortable:false,
            editable:true,
            edittype:'textarea',
            classes:'ui-ellipsis',
            editoptions:{rows:'3',cols:'45'}
        }
    ],
    pager:'#orderMMFoot',
    sortname:'o.id',
    caption:'Minor Materials Ordered for ' + ml_name,
    gridComplete: function() {
        $('.jqgrow').each(function(i) {
            var ordqty = $(this).find('td.qtyOrd').text();
            var ordrec = $(this).find('td.qtyRec').text();
            if ((+ordqty == +ordrec) && (ordrec !== null) && (ordrec != 'undefined')) {
                $(this).find('td.qtyRec').addClass('complete');
            } else {
                $(this).find('td.qtyRec').addClass('incomplete');
            };
        });
    },
    afterSaveCell: function(rowid) {
        var jqRow = $('tr#' + rowid);
        var ordqty = jqRow.find('td.qtyOrd').text();
        var ordrec = jqRow.find('td.qtyRec').text();
        if ((+ordqty == +ordrec) && (ordrec !== null) && (ordrec != 'undefined')) {
            jqRow.find('td.qtyRec').addClass('complete');
        } else {
            jqRow.find('td.qtyRec').addClass('incomplete');
        };
    },
    onSelectRow: function(id) {
        if(id && id !== lastSel) {
            mmGrid.jqGrid('restoreRow',lastSel);
            mmGrid.jqGrid('editRow',id,true);
            lastSel = id;
        }
    },
    editurl:'/jqg/jqg.saveMinorMaterialEdit.php'
});
mmGrid.jqGrid('navGrid','#orderMMFoot',{add:false,edit:false,del:true});
mmGrid.jqGrid('inlineNav','#orderMMFoot',{add:true,edit:true,del:true,editParams:myEditParam,addParams:{addRowParams:myAddParam}});
```

**Optional Code with `autocomplete` in oneditfunc**

```
var mmGrid = $('#orderMMGrid'),
    editingRowId,
    myEditParam = {
        keys: true,
        oneditfunc: function(id) {
            editingRowId = id;
            alert('#' + id + '_mastec_partno');
            $('#' + id + '_mastec_partno').autocomplete({
                source: function(request, response) {
                    $.getJSON('/json/json.searchmultiMaterials.php',{term:request.term,type:'m'},function(data) {
                        response(data);
                    })
                },
                minLength: 2,
                select: function(e,ui) {
                    $(e).val(ui.item.id);
                    $('input[name="description"]').text(ui.item.description);
                    $('input[name="vendor_id"]').val(ui.item.vendor_id);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        },
        afterrestorefunc: function(id) {
            editingRowId = undefined;
        }
    },
    myAddParam = {
        rowID: 'new',
        position:'last',
        extraparam: {
            ml_id: ml_id
        }
    };
```

Inline editing seems to be working. The extraParams is working. The autocomplete is not.

One of the problems seems to be the `#inner-editor` element that is created within the field during **inline editing**.

Following several posted answers / examples, I have tried `autocomplete` in *searchoptions*, and *oneditfunc*, to no avail. It is critical that the **mastec_partno** be an `autocomplete` so that the correct values can be placed into the other two fields

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem has been solved! I have successfully activated `autocomplete` in the field that I was concerned with, using the following code:

**Parameter Settings**

```
var mmGrid = $('#orderMMGrid'),
    editingRowId,
    myEditParam = {
        keys: true,
        oneditfunc: function(id) {
            editingRowId = id;
        },
        afterrestorefunc: function(id) {
            editingRowId = undefined;
        }
    },
    myAutoCompOpts = {
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.getJSON('/json/json.searchmultiMaterials.php',{term:request.term,type:'m'},function(data) {
                response(data);
            })
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(e,ui) {
            $('input:text[name="description"]').val(ui.item.description); // this is now working!
            $('select[name="vendor_id"]').val(ui.item.vendor_id); // this is now working!!
        }
    },
    myAddParam = {
        rowID: 'new',
        position:'last',
        extraparam: {
            ml_id: ml_id
        }
    };
```

**colModel Code to activate autocomplete**

```
{   name:'mastec_partno',
    index:'mastec_partno',
    width:120,
    sortable:false,
    editable:true,
    classes:'ui-ellipsis',
    edittype:'text',
    editoptions:{
        size:22,
        dataInit:function(e) {
            $(e).autocomplete(myAutoCompOpts); // this did the trick
        }
    },
    editrules:{required:true}
},
```

Now, based on this code and the `select` callback from `autocomplete`, I have also been able to successfully change the `value` in the **vendor_id** colModel / field, but am still unable to modify the **description** colModel / field. Here is the code for it:

```
{   name:'vendor_id',
    index:'o.vendor_id',
    width:75,
    sortable:true,
    sorttype:'text',
    align:'left',
    editable:true,
    classes:'ui-ellipsis',
    edittype:'select',
    formatter:'select',
    editoptions:{dataUrl:'/jqg/jqg.selVendors.php',readonly:true},
    editrules:{required:true}
},
{   name:'description',
    index:'description',
    width:180,
    sortable:false,
    align:'left',
    editable:true,
    classes:'ui-ellipsis',
    edittype:'text',
    editoptions:{size:33,readonly:true}, // moved readonly here
    editrules:{required:true}
},
```

The ONLY problem I am having now is getting the `vendor_id` field to re-appear after the edit.